# How do I put multiple pages under one domain?

Tags: python

So, i have a few app pages that i would like to put under urls like this

constants.heroku.com/physics/planck

constants.heroku.com/physics/e

constants.heroku.com/physics/standardgravitation

My app.py for the plancks constant app looks like this.

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('plancksconstant')
app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])

@app.route('/physics/planck')
def hello():
    return '6.626068E-34'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

the url for this app is http://nameless-sands-2295.herokuapp.com/physics/planck. I got the end part working correctly (/physics/planck) but the beginning of the url is still the name of the app (nameless-sands-2295). How do I change that to be "constants" instead of the name of the app?

solved it!!!!
just did this

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('plancksconstant')
app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])

@app.route('/physics/planck')
def hello():
    return '6.626068E-34'

@app.route('/physics/standardgravity')
def hello():
    return '9.8'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to set these up to use "constants.heroku.com" - that's a subdomain of the heroku.com domain, which is obviously not yours to use. However you can set up a domain of your own using any domain registrar (Personally, I like gandi.net but there are a million options).

Once you've found & purchased a suitable domain, you'll need to set up an A record in your zone file (for way too much information on that, here's wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file). That will redirect all requests to, e.g., "planckconstants.com" to your heroku app, without displaying the heroku app url to the end user.

Comment: isn't nameless-sands-2295 a subdomain too? I can change it to whatever I want by renaming the app(in settings), but I want multiple apps to have the same one.

Comment: Wait. Are you asking whether you can set up three separate heroku apps, each one of which returns a constant value, and give the all the same name in heroku? Because the answer would still be no. Two separate heroku apps can't share a name (you'll figure this out quickly if you try to change the name of an app to the name of an existing app.) You can, however, set up multiple flask routes within one app, and rename that app "constants" (unless that name's already taken), which would live at constants.herokuapp.com.